# SQL Server 2008 Before Insert Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have the following Query:

```
Insert into tblTest (ID, Name, Age) VALUES (1, 'TestName', 20);
```

In my trigger I want to check - if the query's ID is equal to 1, send another query:

```
Insert into tblTest (ID, Name, Age) VALUES (2, 'TestName', 21);
```

Else, dont do anything.

The problem is, I dont know how to keep the parameters as is and just change the age, so basically I want to send the SAME query, and change a certain parameter (in this case, its the age parameter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rows about to be inserted can be found in the special `inserted` table.  Here's an example:

```
if object_id('tblTest') is not null 
    drop table tblTest
create table tblTest (id int, name varchar(50), age int)
go
create trigger trg_tblTest_BeforeInsert
on tblTest
after insert
as begin
    insert  tblTest
    select  id + 1
    ,       name
    ,       age + 1
    from    inserted
    where   id = 1 -- Only for rows with id=1
end
go
insert tblTest (id, name, age) values (1, 'TestName', 20)
select * from dbo.tblTest
```

This prints:

```
id  name      age
1   TestName  20
2   TestName  21
```

Comment: Thanks, but if my table look different, for example, a table with 20 columns and I need to change 1 column and insert it, I should write all columns one by one?

Comment: Yes it's best to write out all columns.  To save typing, right click the table in SSMS and chose "Script As -> Select".  That generates a basic column list.

Comment: OK, great. now about: insert tblTest (id, name, age) values (1, 'TestName', 20), is there any way to just run the user's query instead of writing it as hardcoded? like, if the user sent other details instead of 1, 'TestName', 20. if I wont write it at all, would it send it anyway?

Comment: The `insert ... values ...` line is just a test case.  A trigger applies to any query that affects the table.

Comment: Is it possible to run the trigger only if ID=1 ? if so, where should I place this condition?

Comment: A trigger will always run, but you can add a condition inside the trigger.  I've edited the answer to include an example condition.